# Typescript removes (tree-shaking) my file/class

Tags: typescript, tree-shaking

Suppose a class adds itself to an other class as follows

`bar.ts`:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

export class Bar {}

Foo.prop = Bar;
```

And file `foo.ts`

```
export class Foo {
    public static prop: any;
}
```

Now, if would like to use this in `index.ts`

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

console.log(Foo.prop); // -> undefined
```

It is undefined. It looks like that `bar.ts` is not used at all (probably tree shaking). So I can fix that as follows:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';
import { Bar } from './bar';

new Bar(); // trick!
console.log(Foo.prop); // -> Bar
```

Is there a way to tell typescript to include `Bar` anyway, because the solution I showed is ugly.

For completeness, here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom", "dom.iterable"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "dist"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.prop = Bar;`

is what is causing the issue, you're doing this in Bar.ts, do this in Foo.ts, now when you create a new object of Foo in index.ts, tree shaking won't remove Bar.ts.

As a general rule, if you need to add a dependency to a class,always do that in the file where the class is defined (Foo.ts in this case)

Comment: I understand, but thats not going to work for me, unfortunate. The reason I want this is because of a dependency injection library ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/di-xxl ) At the end you have decorators like `@Injectable` which registeres the class to the DI class (basically the same thing as my question describes). I just migrated that lib to typescript and now it doesn't work any more :(

Comment: You could use a typescript based DI Library, like typedi(extremely simple) or inversify ( A bit confusing in the start, but powerful if you understand it well!)

Comment: Only other solution I see here it so do what you have done, and force create an object of type Bar in index.ts.

Comment: I've written a tool which injects the imports such that typescript uses the files. Works pretty well. I think that angular does more or less the same thing with its `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})`